# Restore dead Partition on hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

Volume on which I had installed my ubuntu died.
The other one (600GB) is working good and I can write and delete.

But I can't Open "partition 1"
Is there any way to restore it's content?

http://i065.radikal.ru/1407/c9/4deb70f2172d.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, **stop when you've fixed the issue**:
 1. Install gparted by `sudo apt-get install gparted` or other means.
 2. Open gparted by `sudo gparted`.
 3. Navigate to the dead partition. Does gparted call it anything? Is it still unknown?
 4. Right-click the partition and hit "check". (you could also do `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` if it fails)
 5. Attempt manual mount by doing `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`.
6. Navigate to `/mnt` and check if your files are there.
7. This is becoming dangerous now. Install testdisk by `sudo apt-get install testdisk`.
8. Run testdisk and scan your partition for missing partitions. If it finds something over your broken partition, you may try to overwrite the old copy with the new copy.
9. This is even more dangerous. This is NOT RECOMMENDED, but if you have no other option, it might still work. Reopen `gparted`.
10. Under Device, select "Attempt Data Rescue". If it does not work, keep going.
11. Delete (not format) your broken partition.
12. Under Device, select "Attempt Data Rescue" again.
13. Come back to askubuntu.com and look for other answers....I'm spent.

Comment: I stopped at 5th. It was still unknow in gparted and I could not do check but **fsck** helped. THanks